# Font Awesome all.js file not working in ie9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-awesome

I downloaded the pro fontawesome file to use in my web app. I can't use the CDN. I have inserted the all.js file properly as it is working fine in ie11 and all other browsers. I need it to also work in ie9 though. It does work using the CDN in ie9, but I can't deploy the site using the CDN. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I try to download the font awesome files and use in my app. In IE9 browser, when using all.js, it will display the "Unable to get property 'add' of undefined or null reference" error. The issue is related to the IE9 doesn't support `classList`, so we'll need a polyfill like [classList.js](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js). Then, you could use the font awesome file reference, instead of using the CDN reference.

Code like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Font Awesome 5 Icons</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link href="fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="classList.min.js"></script> <!--https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classlist/1.2.20171210/classList.min.js-->
    <script src="polyfill.classList.min.js"></script> <!--https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eligrey-classlist-js-polyfill@1.2.20171210/classList.min.js-->
    <script src="fontawesome/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>fas fa-tty</h1>

    <i class='fas fa-tty'></i>
    <i class='fas fa-tty' style='font-size:24px'></i>
    <i class='fas fa-tty' style='font-size:36px'></i>
    <i class='fas fa-tty' style='font-size:48px;color:red'></i>
    <br>
    <span style="font-size: 3em; color: Tomato;">
        <i class="fas fa-igloo"></i>
    </span>

    <span style="font-size: 48px; color: Dodgerblue;">
        <i class="fas fa-igloo"></i>
    </span>

    <span style="font-size: 3rem;">
        <span style="color: Mediumslateblue;">
            <i class="fas fa-igloo"></i>
        </span>
    </span>
</body>
```

the result (using F12 change to IE 9):

[image]

Comment: I don't have much experience using polyfills. Is there a site where I can download these files?

Comment: Also, are there separate polyfill files for each version of ie?